# Windows Phone 8.1 Trimming An MP3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

im trying to trim an mp3 file except every time it returns the error bad profile, i have been at this for 2 days, trying every bit of information i can find.

This is what i have so far. (i know its abit of a mess, im still faily new to C# and i just want to get it working to now)

```
    async void TrimFile()
    {

        StorageFolder OutFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        StorageFile OutFile = await OutFolder.GetFileAsync("test.mp3");
        var destFile = OutFile;

        StorageFolder Infolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile InFile = await Infolder.GetFileAsync("test.mp3");
        var srcFile = InFile;

        MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Low);

        MediaTranscoder transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();

        transcoder.TrimStartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);

        transcoder.TrimStopTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

        PrepareTranscodeResult prepareOp = await transcoder.PrepareFileTranscodeAsync(srcFile, destFile, profile);

        if (prepareOp.CanTranscode)
        {
            var transcodeOp = prepareOp.TranscodeAsync();
            transcodeOp.Progress += new AsyncActionProgressHandler<double>(TranscodeProgress);
            transcodeOp.Completed += new AsyncActionWithProgressCompletedHandler<double>(TranscodeComplete);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (prepareOp.FailureReason)
            {
                case TranscodeFailureReason.CodecNotFound:
                    TextBlock1.Text = "No Codec";
                    break;
                case TranscodeFailureReason.InvalidProfile:
                    TextBlock1.Text = "Invalid Profile";
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

if someone could help point me in the right direction thanks.